# Firebase Invite is unable to send email

Tags: firebase, firebase-invites

I have followed the example at https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android for firebase invite and written an app which is able to send invites with SMS without any problem. The same fails to send any email .I am not getting error in onActivityResult() but I don't receive any mail.

Note : SHA1 is added in Firebase console.
Also dynamic link is enabled.
Also the Firebase Invite example programme has no issue and I could make it work both for email and SMS

Comment: This is the app which can be tested and you can see SMS invites working but not the email invites https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoogaru.quikc here you can check it by clicking invite friends button in the empty channel screen. I spent many hours without any luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me removing the portion of code to set other client id, but then on the other client it opens the wrong store...